# Get underlying type for a template used in decltype

Tags: c++11, atomic, decltype

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> bar;

auto foo() -> decltype(bar)
{
        return bar++;
}
```

I receive this gcc error message:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
```

Changing the type in `decltype()` to `int` works. To keep my code more general how can I get the type `int` as defined between the `<>`?

Comment: You can't copy atomic: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic

Comment: I want to know the type! I know I cannot copy atomic. This is not the point!

Comment: "Changing the type in decltype() to int works" ... This statement does not show that! .  Either you ask clear questions, or don't ask at all.

Comment: Thank you Ajed. Edward could understand my unclear question.

Comment: @AJed: It's perfectly clear. You are the only one not understanding. Look to yourself before you criticise others.

Comment: @AlBundy: Yeah, and the rest of us, who got here several minutes before Edward!!

Comment: The only reason tat made me "criticize" is the tone of Al Bundy answer .. nothing more. + my answer is to: "Changing the type in decltype() to int works"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
auto foo() -> decltype(bar.operator++())
{
    return bar++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don’t want to return something the same type as bar…

≥ C++98

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    return bar++;
}
```

≥ C++11

```
auto foo() -> decltype(bar++) {
    return bar++;
}
```

≥ C++14

```
auto foo() {
    return bar++;
}
```

Notice how straightforward the C++11 syntax looks when we come from C++14 (although boilerplate).

Comment: OK, but what to write when I want to use it in the getter function for bar? I used bar.load() as suggested by Lightness Races in Orbit - this works for me.

Comment: Then ask such a question…

Comment: No, it is already answered. I just replied to your answer where you specifically replied to bar++ function and may be you would suggest me another possibility instead of suggesting me to ask a question. All is answered in this thread!

Comment: Your question is not about obtaining the stored value directly, where you would use `bar.load()` indeed, because you cannot infer the type from `std::atomic<T>::operator T` in a generic context.

Comment: Thank you Darklighter. Sometimes a "sub-question" comes up while a thread which was here the case. I did not consider it to create a new question because it was already answered but I am always curious if there is more than 1 solution and therefore I asked you. Regards!

Comment: The point was, that you can (and should) write the same thing inside decltype as you use in the function body. Where in the `get` case I’d suggest using `bar.load()` in both cases instead of relying on implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `std::atomic` doesn't have a `value_type` member or anything like that, so this is not "trivial". Well, it is, but sort of not. Meh.

If you're stuck with C++11:

```
auto foo() -> decltype(bar.load())
{
    return bar++;
}
```

Since C++14, though, you may simply write:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> bar;

auto foo()
{
    return bar++;
}
```

Comment: I used it in CUDA environment and few days ago NVIDIA released finally CUDA 7.0 understanding c++11 so there is no chance for c++14 - may be in 2 years.

Comment: @AlBundy: I'm still on C++03 :)